# How to resize element height and center child elements with animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making some chat controls *(toolbox)* for a messenger. This tool is used to open/close chat controls *(camera, crop...)*

```js
$(document).on('click', '.messenger-tools .tool-main', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find('*').toggleClass('fas fa-th').toggleClass('fas fa-times')
        .closest('.messenger-tools').toggleClass('medium');
});
```

```css
.messenger-tools {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: calc(42px + 20px);
    right: calc(8px + 58px + 8px);
    border-radius: 9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    height: calc(8px + 40px + 8px);
    width: calc(8px + ((40px + 8px) * 3) + 8px);
    line-height: calc(8px + 40px + 8px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.messenger-tools .list-inline {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 8px
}

.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-item,
.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-main {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px
}

.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-item [class^="fa"],
.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-main [class^="fa"] {
    font-size: 13px
}

.messenger-tools.medium {
    height: 40px !important;
    width: 40px !important;
    line-height: unset !important
}

.messenger-tools.medium .list-inline {
    margin-right: 0 !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<div class="bg-white shadow-sm messenger-tools medium">
    <div class="position-relative w-100 h-100">
        <div class="list-inline">
            <div class="list-inline-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn border rounded-circle bg-light shadow-sm tool-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-camera text-dark"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="list-inline-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn border rounded-circle bg-light shadow-sm tool-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-crop-alt text-dark"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="list-inline-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn border rounded-circle bg-light shadow-sm tool-main">
                    <i class="fas fa-th text-dark"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck while clicking on it. When I click to *open*, toolbox will be jumped down before the animation starts. And otherwise, when I click again to *close*, toolbox will be jumped up first.

Can you please exaplain me why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the medium class like below:

```
.messenger-tools.medium {
    width: calc(40px + 8px)!important;
    box-shadow: 0 .125rem .25rem rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
}
```

and remove the last part of the CSS. The jumping is mainly due to the `line-height` you are setting to `unset` that will get removed when you toggle the class:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.messenger-tools .tool-main', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find('*').toggleClass('fas fa-th').toggleClass('fas fa-times')
        .closest('.messenger-tools').toggleClass('medium');
});
```

```css
.messenger-tools {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: calc(42px + 20px);
    right: calc(8px + 58px + 8px);
    border-radius: 9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    height: calc(8px + 40px + 8px);
    width: calc(8px + ((40px + 8px) * 3) + 8px);
    line-height: calc(8px + 40px + 8px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.messenger-tools .list-inline {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 8px
}

.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-item,
.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-main {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px
}

.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-item [class^="fa"],
.messenger-tools .list-inline .tool-main [class^="fa"] {
    font-size: 13px
}

.messenger-tools.medium {
    width: calc(40px + 8px)!important;
    box-shadow: 0 .125rem .25rem rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
}

/*.messenger-tools.medium .list-inline {
    margin-right: 0 !important
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<div class="bg-white shadow-sm messenger-tools medium">
    <div class="position-relative w-100 h-100">
        <div class="list-inline">
            <div class="list-inline-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn border rounded-circle bg-light shadow-sm tool-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-camera text-dark"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="list-inline-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn border rounded-circle bg-light shadow-sm tool-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-crop-alt text-dark"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="list-inline-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn border rounded-circle bg-light shadow-sm tool-main">
                    <i class="fas fa-th text-dark"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice try! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using 'all' for CSS transition.
I suggest using more specific transition like you want to animate on click of the icon, so you can use width transition instead of all.

here is your updated messenger-tools class.

```css
.messenger-tools {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: calc(42px + 20px);
    right: calc(8px + 58px + 8px);
    border-radius: 9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    height: calc(8px + 40px + 8px);
    width: calc(8px + ((40px + 8px) * 3) + 8px);
    line-height: calc(8px + 40px + 8px);
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease;
    transition: width 0.5s ease
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried your suggestion. The toolbox is still jumped to the target position before the animation is completed. Can we make it move to the target position at the same time with the animation?